# C++ binary file with records: string at beginning

Tags: c++, string, file, binary

I am struggeling with reading from a binary file.

My binary file is made of records in the way like:

string - 5 x integers

The first string has differenct lengths, so I guess this may be my problem?

I try to read a record into a class which has the same type of attributes:

```
class Team
{
private:
    string teamName;
    int matchesPlayed;
    int gamesWon;
    int gamesLost;
    int pointsWon;
    int pointsLost;

public:
    Team(string ="",int = 0,int = 0, int = 0, int = 0, int = 0);
    ~Team();

    //void operator<();

    void setTeamName(string);
    void setMatchesPlayed(int);
    void setGamesWon(int);
    void setGamesLost(int);
    void setPointsLost(int);
    void setPointsWon(int);

    void print();
};
```

I try to read in from another class:

```
Table::Table()
{
    Team t1;
    teams.push_back(t1);
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("tabletennis.dta", ios::in | ios::binary);

    if(!inputFile)
    {
        cout << "Datei konnte nicht geoeffnet werden!";
        exit(1);
    }

    if(inputFile.good())
            inputFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&t1), sizeof(Team));

    t1.print();
}
```

Team::print() just prints out the content of its attributes. But the program crashes when I try to print the string.

I don't know what I may understood wrong.. but what I thought was:

Reading in to an Object with the same count and type of attributes is they way how to read a record set:

```
Team::Team(string teamName, int matchesPlayed, int gamesWon, int gamesLost, int pointsWon, int pointsLost)
{
    setTeamName(teamName);
    setMatchesPlayed(matchesPlayed);
    setGamesWon(gamesWon);
    setGamesLost(gamesLost);
    setPointsWon(pointsWon);
    setPointsLost(pointsLost);
}
```

Don't know for now..

Answer (score 1):

Yep, if you want to do record-based I/O, then the records must really all have the same length. and record-based I/O is a rare occasion when using an array of char may be a better bet than a std::string. I would change this:

```
class Team
{
private:
    string teamName;
    int matchesPlayed;
    int gamesWon;
    int gamesLost;
    int pointsWon;
    int pointsLost;
```

to:

```
class Team
{
private:
    char teamName[NAMESIZE];
    int matchesPlayed;
    int gamesWon;
    int gamesLost;
    int pointsWon;
    int pointsLost;
```

You can then read and write:

```
Team t( .... ); // construct a team
os.write( (const char *) & t, sizeof( t ) );
```

and read:

```
Team t;    // default construct empty team
is.read( (char *) & t, sizeof( t ) );
```

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: OR You could write the size of the data before the data, so you would know how much data to read in case of a non-POD structure with Strings.

Comment: @Als That would make doing random access, the main reason for using record-based I/O, very difficult.

Comment: @Neil: I have one more question.. how can i set NAMESIZE for the char array if I do not know how long every teamName is.. ? Wouldn't that go bad if I choose eg char teamName[30] ?

Comment: @Stefan You have to choose a fixed-size big enough to hold any team name. And if a team name longer than this comes along, you have to detect it and report it as an error.

Comment: this works at least for the teamName, but for the integers I don't get the right values.. maybe I have to check for Endian Format.. don't know yet. What keeps me still up is that the exercise definetely tells to use a C-String (std::string) as attribute for Team.. so I guess this has to work also in another way?

Comment: @stefan you can use a std::string (which I would not say was a C-string) in your class, but when you write it to disk, you must write it as a fixed-length string if you want to do record-based I/O. And endianness should not be an issue if you are reading and writing on the same platform.

Comment: In my opinion I remember C-String as a char*.. at least it is told in the exercise to use a C-String as std::string.. seems to be a mistake, but doesn't work also.. I'll give a shot to my Prof and ask for some hints, guess Detail is everything. Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing more to add to the answer of Neil but
I would suggest that you take a look at [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).
If your file format is not fixed and you can easily change it, this will really help you to avoid a lot of traps in serialization.

Comment: To End this question up there is no other way to get this solved properly without using getline(); Thanks everyone for your kind advices :)